# Draw and zoom a imageview in android

Tags: android, imageview

I would make a imageview which I can drawed and zoomed. But I doesn't know how to do draw and zoom together in imageview.

How I can do this?

I need your help.

Comment: https://github.com/hsmnzaydn/image-zoom-view

Comment: @Quicklearner But I can would full zoom

Comment: @Quicklearner I doesn't would imageview size change